# How oracle index hint can be passed to ExpressionBuilder in eclipselink. We are using session.readAllObjects method

Tags: eclipselink

How oracle index hint can be passed to ExpressionBuilder in eclipselink. We are using session.readAllObjects method.

ExpressionBuilder  doesn't support it. Is there any other way.

Comment: hints aren't used in expressions, they are used in JPA to set properties on the underlying query object.  If you are using native API, just use the expression to  create a query and set what you need on it directly.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow I tried below one. It worked.
We can use below ReadAllQuery class instead of session.readAllObjects(Class,Expression)

```
ReadAllQuery raq = new ReadAllQuery(); 
raq.setReferenceClass(MyClass.class); 
raq.setSelectionCriteria(expBuilder.getExpression()); 
  //Query hint in set as below 
raq.setHintString("/*+ index(t0 INDEXNAME)*/"); 
session.executeQuery(raq);
```